# how to revert/rebase for second time?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Sorry this is very confusing.
I have local branch A, i did some work on it and pushed it. I saw a merge conflict so i pulled from master but after merging i saw “your branch A and origin/A are detached”. I did a rebase to fix the issue but now this is what i see:

```
A branch: a - b - c
Master commits: 1 - 2 - 3
After pull i got:
A: a - b - c - 1 - 2 - 3
```

Then i did rebase but i messed up somehow and i ended up having:

```
 A: a- b - c -[1 - 2 - 3 - a - b - c - 1 - 2 - 3]
```

Which 1-2-3 are other people’s commits to master.
a-b-c are my commits.
I only want my commits: a - b - c. How can i revert all the  parts inside brackets?
Goal: 
A: a - b - c

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command to revert to a particular commit or branch or tag:
`git reset --hard <tag/branch/commit id>`

In your case, you need to provide commit id of your latest commit which you want to keep (for example commit id of commit c).